# Passing an integer in C to a process

Tags: linux

How do I pass an integer values, say stored in x, to a child process that is reading it from Process A.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to do that. Pipes or named pipe or unix domain socket is one of the suitable for your requirements.

Comment: for instance if I use pipe to write to a process I will use write(p[1], int*x) or something like that?? I am not sure what is the correct prototype